# Rails with authlogic and omniauth

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, authlogic, authlogic-oauth

I've seen quite a few tutorials, and I've completed a few implementations of simply 'connecting' social accounts to authlogic using an authorizations model. But I'm having trouble coming across something that explains how people have implemented the 'signup with a normal authlogic account' OR 'signup with facebook'.

I see many implementations of this like Spotify, and Pinterest for instane, but how do you normalize the accounts? How do you handle the case when a user forgets they signed up with Facebook? How do you get around Authlogic not having a password when the user signs up using Facebook?